# export_inference_graph with google function or cloudML serverless

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-functions, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I use the TensorFlow models object detection to train a model on the cloud with this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md) and I would like to know if there is an option to export the model also with the Cloud ML engine or with Google Cloud Function?
In their tutorial there is an only [local example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md)
I have train model and now I don't want to create an instance (or use my laptop) to create the exported .pb file for inference
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Tutorials:

- https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras
- https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-tensorflow-estimator